# how to use nav link in react with router and bootstrap style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am now using `react-router-dom` and `react-bootstrap` these 2 packages with `react`. Now I have added `<Nav.Link>` for bootstrap css style(as below)

```
<Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
```

now how I can use `<Link to=">` for router and keep the page style like above?
Like this

```
<Link to="/">Home</Link>
```

Comment: i would probably start here https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic , and then, look at this https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/alerts , and then try and combine those two. Then, if you run into issues, put the full code here and let us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `as` prop

```
<Nav.Link to="/" as={Link}>Home</Nav.Link>
```